# is XMPP still alive for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xmpp

I want to implement chat client for iphone using jabber/XMPP. The XMPP framework on google repository shows that it is depreciated. Does someone knows where to start for xmpp chat client for iPhone?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312847/how-do-chat-ios-applications-communicate/10312934#10312934


See this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jon Parise mentioned, the [XMPP Framework Google Code Project](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/) is quite active.  I have personally written two different XMPP IM clients using the Framework which are accepted and selling in the iPhone app store.  It takes some project setup to get working right, which you can find scattered around the linked site.  For easy reference, I have summarized the required steps (after adding the XMPP Framework source tree to your project) as:

```
//  In order to use the XMPP Framework on iPhone/iPad, need to:    
//  1. add libidn.a to Frameworks (found in libidn folder under XMPP/Vendor folder)
//  2. add libresolv.dylib to Frameworks
//  3. add CFNetwork.framework to frameworks
//  4. add SystemConfiguration.framework to frameworks
//  5. set up XCode to use libxml2: (for KissXML)
//     add "-lxml2" to "Other Linker Flags" under "Linking"
//     add "/usr/include/libxml2" to "Header Search Paths" under "Search Paths"
```

**EDIT May 2013**

As deepwinter points out in the comments, the XMPP Framework moved (quite a while ago) to github.  Get it from https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework these days..

Answer (score 1):

XMPP is now available in Github.

https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework

Comment: Thanks for making this available, but it seems to be a snapshot of the code.google.com repository from September 2011. The problem is that the original project is getting vital updates all the time and I don't think they are propagated to your repository...

Comment: Robbie Hanson's code seems to now be the most up to date (2013)

Comment: This is the proper place to grab XMPP Framework from now (at least, it's where I get updates to it).

Answer (score 0):

The [xmppframework](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/) project on Google Code appears to be under active development.

Comment: As of beginning of October 2011... Problem 1: Their checkout option is broken. You have no way to download the code, except manually via the "browse" option (good luck...) Problem 2: Their Google group is moderated and so far, my question regarding problem 1 has not passed-through yet.