# How do chat iOS applications communicate?

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, xamarin.ios

How do text chatting in applications like Whatsapp and Skype communicate? Specifically, how are messages *received* real time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107172/what-mechanisms-used-by-whatsapp-and-viber-for-chatting-and-messaging

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is related with what is called Socket programming in iOS. you may refer to apple developer documentation for that or [this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server) can help you regarding this.

Following links infact would be very helpful:

http://blog.scriptico.com/08/iphone-chat-native-rtmp-library-for-ios-in-action/

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/series/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios/

Whatsapp which uses XMPP also based upon socket programming.

Thanks

Comment: +1 for the great question and i am also working on chat in my current application, which is a lil bit diffrent from my prev app in which i incorporated XMPP for facebook and gtalk chat. have nice day